# How to make jQuery Mobile Anchors work?

Tags: jquery, mobile, anchor

I have this link:

```
<a rel="external" href="/feed/123/#comment">comment</a>
```

When I go to that page this is what happens:
- The browser takes me to the  anchor, but after a fraction of a second I go back to the top. I've tried this:

```
$(window.document).bind("mobileinit", function() {
    $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
    $.mobile.changePage.defaults.changeHash = false;
    $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
});
```

So, none of it helped. I also tried on `pagecreate` event to do something like `window.location.href = window.location.hash`. It did not work.

Can anyone shed some light into this mystery?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried :

```
<div data-role="page">
<a rel="external" href="#comments">comment</a>
...
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="comments">
...
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I found this line in jqm 1.2.0:   `$window.load( $.mobile.silentScroll );`

Comment it out, then it won't scroll back to top. Maybe it's there to cater for older iOS browsers, because I don't see a difference on my ipod touch(iOS 5).